# VBA Check to see if file is open before reopening a second file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm having one of those moments, what I'm wanting to do is run this code multiple times but for it to check to see if the Powerpoint file is already open before opening a second copy.

I'm expecting it to look to see if the PowerPoint file is open to stop duplication of the file being open

Code below being used to before excel to PPT

````
    \`
    'app
    '  pre
    '   slide
    '    shapes
    '     text frame
    '      text
    
    Sub ExporttoPPT()
    
    Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim slde As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Dim vSheet$
    Dim vRange$
    Dim vWidth As Double
    Dim vHeight As Double
    Dim vTop As Double
    Dim vLeft As Double
    Dim vSlide_No As Long
    Dim expRng As Range
    
    Dim adminSh As Worksheet
    Dim cofigRng As Range
    Dim xlfile$
    Dim pptfile$
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
    Set cofigRng = adminSh.Range("Rng_sheets2")
    
    xlfile = adminSh.\[excelpath2\]
    pptfile = adminSh.\[pptPth\]
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile, False, True)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
    
    For Each rng In cofigRng
    
    '----------------- set VARIABLES
    With adminSh
    vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
    vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
    vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
    vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
    vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
    vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
    vSlide_No = .Cells(rng.Row, 10).Value
    
    ```
          End With
    
    '----------------- EXPORT TO PPT
    
                wb.Activate
                Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
                Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
                expRng.Copy
    
    '            Stop
    
                pre.Application.Activate
                Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
                
                'Application.ActiveWindow.Panes(vSlide_No).Activate
                slde.Select
                slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject 'ppPasteSecial' ppPasteOLEobject
                Set shp = slde.Shapes(slde.Shapes.Count)
                
                            
                With shp
                   
                   .Top = vTop
                   .Left = vLeft
                   .Width = vWidth
                   .Height = vHeight
                   
                End With
                
                
                Set shp = Nothing
                Set slde = Nothing
                Set expRng = Nothing
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set expRng = Nothing
    Next rng
    
    'pre.Save
    'pre.Close
    
    Set pre = Nothing
    Set ppt_app = Nothing
    
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    End Sub\`
````

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the line `Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)` with

```
if not pre is nothing then
      Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
end if
```

The code checks if the `pre` object is set and if not, sets it by opening your `pptfile`

Comment: Thank you, it then goes to a Debug error when it gets to the Set slde = pre.slides(vSlide_No) any idea?

---------------- EXPORT TO PPT

        wb.Activate
        Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
        Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
        expRng.Copy
' Stop

        pre.Application.Activate
        Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)

Comment: Does this line throw an error when you step through the code? `  pre.Application.Activate` ?

Comment: Yes it throws an error 91 on the 'export to PPT' section on the "pre.Application.Activeate" section. When it's  Set pre = ppt_aap.Presenatations.Open(pptfile) it works fine without error

Comment: Ok, surround `pre.Application.Activate` with `if not pre is nothing then`  and `end if` same as my answer

Comment: Hi Nick Like the below  "If Not pre Is Nothing Then
                Set pre = pre.Application.Activate
                 End If
                             
                Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)"  If so i get a compile error

Comment: I think your issue is how you are setting the paths to the `pptfile` and `xlfile` on these lines: `xlfile = adminSh.\[excelpath2\]` and  `pptfile = adminSh.\[pptPth\]`. The paths don't look valid. What is the full path to your files?

Comment: The file paths get pulled from excel from a range. This works fine when i run the VBA normally it's when trying to stop it opening a second PPT from running the strip multiple times to pull the information